# using jquery variable value in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm very new developing.... so although it might sound easy and stupid.... I'm lost :S
I have a html calendar, and I have a users table on the database, with id, user_name, total_holiday and holiday_used. At the moment I did CRUD with the users, so a user can be added, modified or deleted.

On the other hand I have a modal that pops up every time I click on a day on the calendar. This modal displays a select with the list of users, that I read with jQuery from the mark-up where I display the table showing the users and a set of checkboxes, that contains different quantity of hours. (clearer on the image).

[image]

With jQuery I'm taking the value of the selected option on the selected, and I stored it in a variable called selectedOption.

Now, I want to achieve, that when I select a user so there is a value for selectedOption, if I ckeck the mati(7.5h), it sustracts 7.5 hours from this user which the value of user_name's column matches with the selectedOption, and it sustract the hours from the holiday_used column for this user. And the same if I check the checkbox that says mati/tarda(15h) or tarda/nit sustracting 18h.

But because I've done very simple stuff... now I don't know how to even start.... My desk neighbour here at the office told me I have to do it with Ajax, as there is not other way I can pass the value I have stored in selectedOption with jQuery to php what I use to do the query.

So what I've done so far....

This is the modal:

```
  <div id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="modalLabel"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="equipo" action="edit_holiday.php"> 
                <div class="leftColumn">
                  <select id="usuarisLlista">   
                    <option selected disabled>Selecciona un usuari...</option> 
                  </select>
                </div>
              <div class="input_group">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="interval"> 
                 <input type="checkbox" id="interval_check"/>Interval<br />
                <div id="desde">
                  De: <select class="hores" name="holiday_used" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php printf ("%02d",$i); ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>:<select class="minuts" name="holiday_used" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 45; $i+=15) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php printf ("%02d",$i); ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
                </div> <div id="fins">
                fins: <select class="hores" name="holiday_used" disabled>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php printf ("%02d",$i); ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>:<select class="minuts" name="holiday_used" disabled>
                    <?php       
                    for ($i = 0; $i <= 45; $i+=15) : ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php printf ("%02d",$i); ?></option>
                  <?php endfor; ?>
                </select>
                 </div>
                  </div>
                <br>      
                <input type="checkbox" class="torns" name="holiday_used" value="mati">mat&iacute; (7.5h)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="torns" name="holiday_used" value="matiTarda">mat&iacute; / tarda (15h)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="torns" name="holiday_used" value="tardaNit">tarda / nit (18h)<br>
              </div>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>       
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Tancar sense guardar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="hoursSubmission" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar i tancar</button>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then the edit_holiday.php which is the action on the form inside the modal:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

global $conn;

$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$total_holiday = $_GET['total_holiday'];
$holiday_used = $_GET['holiday_used']; 
$holiday_left = $total_holiday - $holiday_used;

     //Here I would put something like:

if (strpos(selectedOption, $user_name) == true) {

  if(mati_checkbox is checked) {

     $holiday_used = 7.5;
     $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
     $query .= "holiday_used = '{$holiday_used}' ";
     $query .= "WHERE id = {$user_id} ";
     $query .= "LIMIT 1";
  }
}
```

But like you can see, my head is a mess. How will holiday used increase its value instead of updating it? Can anyone help me to find the way? maybe telling me some steps to arrive to my objective... how to I use the value of selectedOption to compare it and match it with the user_name column..... something please!

Thank you

Comment: You really have to break down your problem to the relevant stuff. Moreover you collegue is right. You can call a server side script with post parameters via ajax. To simplify the process of ajax many people normally use jquery. I can not see any single line of javascript in your post. You should have a look in the jQuery docs first.

Comment: Is my jquery code relevant? :S I mean....  It is only this:

  $('select#usersList').on('click', function() {
        var selectedOption = ($( "select#usersList option.selectOption:selected" ).val());
        return selectedOption;
});

Nothing else :S

Comment: I would say maybe you are looking in the wrong place by looking at 'using jQuery variable in php'. This isn't possible as PHP is server side and is executed before jQuery exists on the page, client side. You have to post the jQuery value to a PHP page - this can be done via AJAX as your colleague has said or by putting the value in a form and submitting the form.

Comment: Yes your jQuery is probably the most relevant part of this as it could be used to make an AJAX call and it is part of you question. You are asking about using a jQuery value in PHP, if there is no jQuery then we don't know what value you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with AJAX as your colleague says, or, you could populate a hidden field in your form with the value you want with jQuery. Then, when the form posts, PHP will have access to this form field.

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="jQueryValue" id="jQueryField">
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    $('#jQueryField').val('Hello PHP!');

})(jQuery);
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])):
    var_dump($_GET['jQueryValue']);
endif;
```